# PnP SharePoint Powershell command throws exception

Tags: pnp-powershell, pnp

We are using PnP powershell which works as expected. However, sometimes we face an exception intermittently with the error as given below.  The PnP powershell script line is

`Connect-PnPOnline -Url $DestinationSite -Credential (Get-Credential)`

We are able to fix if we reinstall PnP module again. But what is the reason this issue keeps appearing intermittently?

> **Connect-PnPOnline : The 'Connect-PnPOnline' command was found in the module 'SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 
>   'Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline'.
>   At C:\MyMigScript\04a StartOneDriveMigration.ps1:82 char:21
>   +                     Connect-PnPOnline `
>   +                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-PnPOnline:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
>
> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SearchBoxInNavBarType' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Connect-PnPOnline : The
>   'Connect-PnPOnline' command was found in the module
>   'SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline', but the module could not be loaded.
>   For more information, run  'Import-Module
>   SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline'. At C:\MyMigScript\04a
>   StartOneDriveMigration.ps1:82 char:21
>   +                     Connect-PnPOnline `
>   +                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-PnPOnline:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
>
> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SearchBoxInNavBarType' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Connect-PnPOnline : The
>   'Connect-PnPOnline' command was found in the module
>   'SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline', but the module could not be loaded.
>   For more information, run  'Import-Module
>   SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline'. At C:\MyMigScript\04a
>   StartOneDriveMigration.ps1:82 char:21
>   +                     Connect-PnPOnline `
>   +                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-PnPOnline:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule**

Comment: You have an environment issue, or a problem with your script. If you just open the shell and run the command with no arguments, does it prompt you for the url and credentials? Do a little more troubleshooting and provide some more info on how you're running the script.

Comment: @DerekGusoff - we face the error while also running the command Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline. If we  open a new session and try it after sometime it then works! Not sure what is the root cause of it though. Do you have any suggestions/pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this issue? I came across the same issue with my codes. Finally, I found the way to solve it.

I am working on ASP.Net website which contain codes using PowerShell PnP to manipulate SharePoint. First I build a very simple website only containing the codes using PowerShell PnP. It works very good. Then I put these codes back to my old website which contain other codes using SharePoint CSOM, I got exactly the same error as you did.

I tried many different ways and found that it was due to the SharePoint CSOM. I updated the NuGet package of SharepointOnline.CSOM (See below image) to the latest version, that is the 16.1.20616.12000. Then the PowerShell PnP works perfectly fine!

So you could have a try!

Well, in case the image won't show up, I wrote the NuGet package here:

Microsoft.SharepointOnline.CSOM distrubuted by Microsoft

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Late entry here, but...
Look at the `-UseWebLogin` or `-Interactive` switches on the `Connect-PnPOnline` command.

```
Connect-PnPOnline
       [-ReturnConnection]
       [-Url] <String>
       [-TenantAdminUrl <String>]`
       [-UseWebLogin]
       [-Interactive]
       [-ForceAuthentication]
```

`Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com" -UseWebLogin`

`Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com" -Interactive`

See Here:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps